# Can I use django-ckeditor in commercial projects without buying a CKeditor license?

Tags: commercial, bsd

I want to use django-ckeditor in a commercial project.

Django-ckeditor is [licensed](https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor/blob/master/LICENSE) under the BSD 3-clause license, but in CKeditor's official website it says that I've to buy a license to use it in a commercial project.

Now, I'm very confused, do I really have to buy a license from CKeditor's website to use django-ckeditor in my commercial project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CKEditor is available as a commercial license at https://ckeditor.com/ or a choice of GPL/LGPL/MPL at https://github.com/ckeditor

This is the [gist of its terms](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/blob/master/LICENSE.md):

> Licensed under the terms of any of the following licenses at your choice:
>
> - GNU General Public License Version 2 or later (the "GPL")
> - GNU Lesser General Public License Version 2.1 or later (the "LGPL")
> - Mozilla Public License Version 1.1 or later (the "MPL")
>
> You are not required to, but if you want to explicitly declare the license you have chosen to be bound to when using, reproducing, modifying and distributing this software, just include a text file titled "legal.txt" in your version of this software, indicating your license choice. In any case, your choice will not restrict any recipient of your version of this software to use, reproduce, modify and distribute this software under any of the above licenses.

And as @apsilers commented:

> And for the OP's benefit: the weak copyleft options (LGPL and MPL) mean that distributions that include CKEditor as a library only need to include the source of CKEditor itself, not the entire application.

Comment: And for the OP's benefit: the weak copyleft options (LGPL and MPL) mean that distributions that include CKEditor as a library only need to include the source of CKEditor itself, not the entire application.